# Why `#import("dart:unittest")` can't run?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I write some dart test code:

```
#import("dart:unittest");
main() {
  test('this is a test', () {
    int x = 2+3;
    expect(x).equals(5);
  });
}
```

It doesn't display any error in dart editor, but when I press the "run" button, it reports:

```
Do not know how to load 'dart:unittest''file:///home/freewind/dev/dart/editor
/samples/shuzu.org/test/model_test.dart': 
Error: line 1 pos 1: library handler failed
#import("dart:unittest");
^
```

I see there is a "dart:unittest" library in my dart-sdk. Why it can't be run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the unittest library is not yet wired into the dart: namespace. Until that happens, if it ever happens, you'll need to use a relative path to get to the unittest library.

Something like:

```
#import('path-to-dart/lib/unittest/unitest.dart');
```

More examples are here: http://api.dartlang.org/unittest.html

Comment: I surely hope that i does get wired in (or becomes a package in pub), as the current state is just to strange. Really confusing and hard to explain people why you need to use a relative/full path.

Comment: Agreed! This should be more consistent.

Comment: isn't this required for all package (pkg) libraries (args and so on)? Specially when running with Windows?

Answer (score 1):

This page keeps showing up in Google results for `dart` and `unittest`, so I thought I would add an update. The `unittest` library is now installed quite easily through `pub`, Dart's package manager. To do this, make sure that you:

check `Add pub support` when you create a new Dart application. 
Then add (or uncomment) the dependency for the `unittest` package in your `pubspec.yaml` file. That file should look like this:

```
name:  range
description:  A sample application

dependencies:
    unittest: { sdk: unittest }
```

Run `pub install` (although if you are using Dart Editor, this command should automatically get run for you).  Then, in the file where you will be writing your tests, 
add this import declaration:

```
import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
```

And you should be good to go.